# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Debit>0' to data type int

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

```
DECLARE @strCrDr VARCHAR(50) = '';
SET @strCrDr = 'Debit > 0'; 

SELECT *
FROM dbo.Trn_Jounal_Entery
WHERE 1 = 1 + @strCrDr;
```

Comment: Looks like dynamic WHERE condition for me. [SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE @condition](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Condition)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add a string to an int - this causes the problem.

In this expression:

```
WHERE 1 = 1 + @strCrDr;
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

you are trying to **add** the `varchar(50)` variable `@strCrDr` to an `INT` (1) - since those types aren't compatible, SQL Server will try to convert both parameters of this addition to a common type. Based on the [well-defined data type precedence rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), SQL Server will try to convert both side of the addition to `INT` (since `INT` has the **higher precedence** than `varchar`) - which works fine for `1`, but obviously fails for `Debit > 0`.

So you really need to explain / understand what you're doing, and you need to preferably **explicitly convert** both sides of your addition to the **same** data type.